# im adding tomcat server in netbeans IDE but error occur

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

value of `CATALINA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0`

[image: value of CATALINA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0'. click here to see]

> *i want to add server to the netbeans IDE but when im going to add the server then i get an error message that the server.xml file in the config folder is seems to be corrupted. i add an screenshot for better understanding my problem of the error which im facing. and also the code of the server.xml file as the text format.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Server shutdown="SHUTDOWN" port="8005">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" 
SSLEngine="on"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
<Listener 
className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
<Listener 
className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
<Listener 
className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
-<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" 
factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" 
description="User 
database that can be updated and saved" 
type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" auth="Container" 
name="UserDatabase"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
-<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="8080" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="20000" 
protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
<Connector port="8009" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3"/>
-<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
-<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" 
 resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Realm>
-<Host name="localhost" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" 
appBase="webapps">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" pattern="%h %l 
%u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" suffix=".txt" prefix="localhost_access_log" 
directory="logs"/>

</Host>

</Engine>

</Service>

</Server>
```

Comment: [1] Show your value for CATALINA_HOME. [2] Does the file named in the error message actually exist? If so, display its content.

Comment: Please understand that you need to provide more information in your post to resolve this: [1] From the Tomcat 7 installation instructions: _"shell scripts assume that you have set an environment variable **CATALINA_HOME** that contains the pathname to the directory in which Tomcat has been installed"_. I am asking you to update your post to show what you set **CATALINA_HOME** to. [2] Also, update your post to show the content of **conf/server.xml**.

Comment: OK, but **please update your question** with the content of **conf/server.xml** rather than adding the data as comments. Also, **please update your question** with the value you assigned to **CATALINA_HOME**.

Comment: Unfortunately the content of **conf/server.xml** is not rendering properly. Paste its content, select the pasted content, and then click the _Code Sample_ button (the two curly braces). Finally, verify that the content is being displayed correctly in your question.

Comment: im recently added a pic of server.xml file code. please check it and tell me the solution of my problem

Comment: Is that listing of server.xml **exactly** what you are using? It does not look valid. For example, several tags are preceded by a hyphen such as the `<Server>` tag on line two, and you have a line break in the middle of the string value for the `pattern` property of `<Valve>`. It is absolutely crucial that you post the exact content of **server.xml** that is being used by Tomcat to resolve this issue.

Comment: yes i post the exact content of server.xml

Comment: the line break of pattern value is not in the file. it occur when i paste the content here atuomatically

Comment: now tell what i changes should be perform for solve this problem

Comment: when i remove the hyphens from the content error is solved

Comment: You said in one comment that what you posted is "the exact content of server.xml" and yet in the next comment you state "the line break of pattern value is not in the file"! Work out how to display the **exact content of the file** without hyphens and without line breaks.

Comment: no you misuderstand me the hyphen is in the file

Comment: can i tell you about the warning which i get

Comment: Re _"when i remove the hyphens from the content error is solved"_, then the error message was due to errors in **serverl.xml**, and that issue is resolved, right? If you now have another (different) problem create a new question.

Comment: okay then  : (  and thanku again

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your error on a working Tomcat configuration by copying a single change from your **server.xml**:

[image: corruptServerXml]

The change was copied from the `pattern` property of the `<Valve>` element in your **server.xml** screenshot:

`pattern="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b"`

That value is invalid XML because it contains nested quotes ( `"%r"` ).

The fix is simple: replace the nested quotes with their [character entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) equivalents, so that the `pattern` property looks like this:

```
pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"
```

Once that change is made you should be able to add the Tomcat server.

p.s. One other unrelated difference I noticed in your **server.xml** file is that your value of the `prefix` property for the `<Valve>` element is `"localhost_access_log."` but the Tomcat 9 default is `"localhost_access_log"` (without a trailing period).

Comment: i do all the changes you told but im still getting same error.

Comment: and also im using tomcat version 7.0 not 9.0.8

Comment: OK, I understand that you are using a different version of Tomcat though I don't think that would matter for the error you are getting. However, I will try with Tomcat 7. But first update your post with the new content of **server.xml**, but **post it as text rather than a screen shot** so that I can cut and paste the data you are using. If you continue to have problems posting the XML as text just google for details on how this can be done on Stack Overflow.

Comment: still error is coming that too much code in your post

Comment: what can i do .

Comment: OK. I think the problem might be that [the ratio of code to a description of the problem is too high](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354034/error-message-it-looks-like-your-post-is-mostly-code-appear-for-me-while-i/354041#354041), so try adding a better (and longer) description. Also, you can delete the old screen shot of **server.xml** to see if that helps, but posting the current content of **server.xml** as text is crucial.

Comment: i get success in editing the post. please check it and tell me the solution to come out from this problem